# Ignored attempt to cancel a touchmove event with cancelable=false

Tags: ionic4

I am using a ion-datetime picker in ionic 4. This is how I implement it:

in the **home.page.html**

```
 <ion-item color="dark">
    <ion-label>Rest Duration</ion-label>
    <ion-datetime
      display-format="mm:ss"
      placeholder="Tap here"
      [(ngModel)]="fullTime"
    ></ion-datetime>
  </ion-item>
```

in the home.page.ts

```
export class HomePage {
  percent = 0;
  radius = 0;

  fullTime: any = '00:01:30';

  constructor() {}

}
```

Why is it that when I change my date picker it gives me this error?

> [Intervention] Ignored attempt to cancel a touchmove event with
> cancelable=false, for example because scrolling is in progress and
> cannot be interrupted.